# Hausdorff and compactness

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am curious about this problem: Let $X$ be a topological space. If every $Y\subseteq X$ is a discrete space whenever $Y$ is compact, then is it true that $X$ is Hausdorff?

My attempt: let $x,y\in X$. We consider 2 cases

(i) there is $Y\subseteq X$ such that $x,y\in Y$. Since $Y$ is compact and discrete, $\{x\}, \{y\}$ are open in $Y$. So, there are two open sets $A$ and $B$ in $X$ such that $\{x\}=A\cap Y$ and $\{y\}=B\cap Y$. Since
$$(A\cap B)\cap Y=\emptyset,$$
we have $A\cap B=\emptyset$. We deduce $X$ is Hausdorff.

(ii)there are $Y, Z\subseteq X$ such that $x\in Y$ and  $y\in Z$. Since $Y,Z$ are compact and discrete, $\{x\}, \{y\}$ are open in $Y$ and $Z$, respectively. There are open sets $A$ and $B$ in $X$ such that $\{x\}=A\cap Y$ and $\{y\}=B\cap Y$. Since
$$(A\cap B)\cap (Y\cap Z)=\emptyset,$$
we have $A\cap B=\emptyset$. We deduce $X$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey: you are right. I will edit it

Comment: How do you deduce that $A\cap B = \emptyset$ in the first case?

Comment: $(A \cap B) \cap Y = \emptyset$ does not give us $A\cap B = \emptyset$. $A$ and $B$ may intersect outside of $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument in case (i) doesn't quite work: you cannot conclude from $A\cap B\cap Y=\emptyset$ that $A\cap B=\emptyset$; they might intersect at points outside of $Y$.

In case (ii), there is a similar issue.  In fact, in case (ii), nothing would prevent you from taking $Y=\{x\}$ and $Z=\{y\}$, in which case your argument (if it worked) would prove that *every* space is Hausdorff.  However, case (ii) is never actually necessary.  For any $x,y\in X$, the subspace $Y=\{x,y\}\subseteq X$ is compact (since any finite space is compact).

Your proof aside, it turns out that the result you are trying to prove is not true!  As a counterexample, consider the case where $X$ is an uncountable set with the cocountable topology.

Comment: Do you mind explaining why every compact subspace of $\mathbb R$ with the cocountable topology is discrete?

Comment: No infinite set with the cocountable topology is compact (for instance, any countably infinite subset is closed and discrete and hence not compact, and hence the whole space can't be compact because a closed subset of a compact space is compact).  So the only compact subspaces are finite sets.